# How to say I was so angry I could kill him in Japanese

Tags: translation

I tried to translate the phrase, 'I was so angry I could kill him', but I was told by my Japanese girlfriend that, 'aitsu wo koroseru gurai okotta', was unnatural and, 'gaman dekinai gurai okotta', was better.

This is in the context of my explaining 'could' to her to express feeling or extent in English. The sentence comes from a textbook.

What is the best way to translate this sentence in Japanese?

Comment: Is " so angry I could kill *someone* " a common rhetorical expression?

Comment: It's not uncommon, but the point is the speaker doesn't mean they actually had any intention of killing the person they were angry with. It's hyperbolic. Somewhat similar to, 'I'm so hungry, I could eat a horse',

Comment: I usually use "あのクソ野郎をぶっ殺せるぐらいブチ切れた". Always convey's exactly how pi**ed I am/was to my girl. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with your girlfriend's comment.
 I do not know if this translation looks like a textbook answer, but another way to translate that sentence would be 彼を殺そうかと思うくらい怒った(Kare wo korosou kato omou kurai okotta). 
Putting it more formally, 殺意を抱くほどの怒りを覚えた (Satsui wo idaku hodono ikari wo oboeta).